# Checking for words with prefix & suffix

Tags: java, regex, string

I tried but it seems I couldn't find out. The base form of word is "***pakai***" and the modified word (with *prefix*) is "**memakai**".

The prefix is "***me***" but when it gets combined to "***pakai***", it turns the first alphabet "***p***" to "***m***", so "***pakai***" turns to "***makai***".

So ***pakai*** --> ***memakai***.

```
String w1 = "memakai";

String w2 = "pakai";
```

I tried

```
k1.contains(k2) --> false, it's correct since there is no "p" in "memakai"
k1.indexOf(k2) --> -1
```

My question is how to check if *w1* contains in *w2* (*w2* is base form of *w1*). Is there any efficient way to solve this case. Thanks

Comment: If there was a question, I missed it.

Comment: You can try: `k1.contains(k2.substring(1))`

Comment: That works titus, but presumably I want to do it without knowing the  index *'1'* inside *the substring(...)*

Comment: It just removes the first letter from `k2` and checks if `k1` contains this new `String` eg: `"memakai".contains("akai")`.

Comment: wow, this is smart, can you explain the `1`means

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)

Comment: Thank you titus, can you put it on asnwer, you solve it first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
K1="memakai";
K2="pakai";
boolean retVal;
retVal = K1.endsWith( K2.substring(1) );
System.out.println("Returned Value = " + retVal );
```

If you don't know the starting index for  `.substring(StsrtIndex)` use this :

```
boolean retVal=Boolean.FALSE;
for(int i=0; i<(K2.length()-1);i++)
    retVal = K1.endsWith( K2.substring(i) );
System.out.println("Returned Value = " + retVal );
```

Comment: That works, but presumably I want to do it without knowing the index '1' inside the substring(...) –

Comment: If the starting index is variable then you will have to put a loop like `for(int i=0; i<(K2.length()-1);i++)` and check.

Comment: @Bravo I have updated the answer with  the for loop.

Comment: @Bravo Good to know it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment you posted on another answer about not wanting to use the index, I'll add this bit of code. It should satisfy the general requirements for any word with a modified base.

```
boolean isBase(String input, String prefix, String check) {
    return input.startsWith(prefix) &&
           input.substring(prefix.length(), prefix.length()+check.length()).equals(check);
}
```

This way we don't take for granted that it has the prefix nor that only the first character of the base is modified.